# HTML Aligning icons with logo

Tags: html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm having a bit of an issue where I can't get the icons to correctly align.  If I remove the section for all the icons, the Logo & title align perfectly, however when adding the icons, it causes massive issues.  Sorry if this is a silly question, html is new to me!

I'm using a base HTML5 template for the design elements: [HTML5UP Editorial](https://html5up.net/editorial)

HTML & CSS:

```js
/* Header */
#header {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #f56a6a;
  padding: 6em 0 1em 0;
  position: relative; }
  #header > * {
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin-bottom: 0; }
  #header .logo {
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
    font-size: 1.125em; }
  #header .icons {
    text-align: right; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
    #header {
      padding-top: 5em; } }
  @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #header {
      padding-top: 6.5em; }
      #header .logo {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        margin: 0; }
      #header .icons {
        height: 5em;
        line-height: 5em;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0.5em;
        top: 0; } }
        
        

/* Icons */
ul.icons {
  cursor: default;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0; }
  ul.icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0; }
    ul.icons li:last-child {
      padding-right: 0; }
    ul.icons li .icon {
      color: inherit; }
      ul.icons li .icon:before {
        font-size: 1.25em; }
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">

        <div>
        <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right:0.5em;"; src="images/cat-logo.png"; alt=""; width="64"; height="64";/></a>
            <a class="logo"><strong> Oscat Pets</strong></a>
            
            <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-snapchat-ghost"><span class="label">Snapchat</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-medium-m"><span class="label">Medium</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

[Example of Current Broken Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L323.png)

[Example of how Alignment should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYZ4E.png)

[Example of Header without icons being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHTVX.png)

[Example of HTML Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwBIG.png)

Comment: Can you include your current "broken" CSS in the snippet, the html is not much use without it

Comment: Hi @Raxi, I hope I've included the right thing! Since im working from a template, im still learning the ins & outs of what im doing!

Comment: Is that both the css of the template that you use and your own modifications ? the `position` properties in particular seem very out of place ?

Comment: This is all unmodified code from the original template (within main.css)

It works fine when using the template before i added the image in! Adding the image made me have to align the "Oscat Pets" section, which is now working fine.  It simply the icons that force it not to work!

Comment: Yea i see, i've added a working fix in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks all for the feedback & advice! Turns out after about 6 hours of trying lots of different things, all that was missing was a simple statement for the ul class:

```
style="align-self: flex-end;"
```

Text is now being properly aligned although the base code has changed:

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header id="header">
  <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right:0.5em;" src="images/cat-logo.png" alt="" width="64" height="64" />
    <strong> Oscat Pets</strong></a>

  <ul class="icons" style="align-self: flex-end;">
    <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label"; >Facebook</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-snapchat-ghost"><span class="label">Snapchat</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-medium-m"><span class="label">Medium</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Ultimately, there was nothing wrong with the template, I had just used the wrong functions.  Although Raxi's contributions will be taken into consideration, upon further manipulating the project!

Thanks to everyone supporting so quickly on my first post! I really appreciate this, and will be sure to engage fully on this site!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute`.

For further understanding you could try refer this [page](https://css-tricks.com/tips-aligning-icons-text/).

```css
#header .icons {
        height: 5em;
        line-height: 5em;
        position: relative;
        right: -0.5em;
        top: 0; } }
```

Comment: Trying that doesnt seem to result in any changes! Thank you though!

Comment: try position: relative !important; if this still doesnt work try to inspect ur icon and screenshot it

Comment: Ive attached an image "Example of HTML Inspect" to the post, to help guide with this!
Again their is no change!

Comment: could you inspect the logo as well from what I see it might be the fact that the logo and the icons are not in the same row. You wanted it to be on the right of the logo instead adding a new row and align right is it?

Comment: try read through this article. It might have the solution for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315572/place-image-and-ul-on-same-line

Comment: Thanks again, but all of the changes recommended and reading have no effect on the application.

I've managed to line up the left one by combining them together! But the icons are still too high up. they are populating the top, rather than the center! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below code to your css to get it working.

```
#header > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#header > div > ul.icons {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I separate into two div and float the logo div to left

```css
<style>
/* Header */

#header {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: solid 5px #f56a6a;
  padding: 6em 0 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}

#header>* {
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#header .logo {
  border-bottom: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 1.125em;
}

#header .icons {
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
  #header {
    padding-top: 5em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  #header {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  #header .logo {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  #header .icons {
    height: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    right: -0.5em;
    top: 0;
  }
}


/* Icons */

ul.icons {
  cursor: default;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul.icons li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}

ul.icons li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

ul.icons li .icon {
  color: inherit;
}

ul.icons li .icon:before {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}


</style>
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header id="header">

  <div style="float: left;">
    <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right:0.5em;" ; src="images/cat-logo.png" ; alt="" ; width="64" ; height="64" ;/></a>
    <a class="logo"><strong> Oscat Pets</strong></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="icons">
      <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-snapchat-ghost"><span class="label">Snapchat</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-medium-m"><span class="label">Medium</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template CSS you showed has some stuff in there that is either very outdated, or just pretty horrible. Because, even though it explicitly uses flexbox, it then uses oldschool `position`ing and such to do the things that flexbox is actually good at; weird.

Anyway, this should give you all you asked for:

```
        /* reset header CSS to saner defaults */
        #header, #header > div, #header div > a, #header .logo, #header ul.icons, #header ul.icons li, #header ul.icons li .icon {
            position: static;
            display: flex;
            flex: 0 0 auto; 
            height: auto; width: auto;
            line-height: normal;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* now define the header layout */
        #header              { padding: 1em; }
        #header > div        { width: 100%;    flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center; align-content: center; gap: 1.0em; }
        #header ul.icons     { flex: 1 1 auto; flex-flow: row wrap;   justify-content: flex-end;   align-items: center; align-content: center; gap: 0.5em; }
```

Just place that CSS in your stylesheet (somewhere under/after the template code).

Be aware by the way, your `<a ... class="logo">` element contains some odd `;`s. You use `;` separators inside the `style=""` argument, but not outside it in the HTML.

Comment: Using this, you can also remove the inline CSS that you're currently using on your logo image (the `style=...` argument).